# Cannot pass state using useNavigate() in react router dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hi I was trying to pass a value to another page using useNavigate, when a button is pressed (button B), it calls the function, which contains the navigate function that I got from the useNavigate() hook, then I use the useLocation() hook to obtain the value.

It is very weird to me that the `console.log(score)` prints out the correct value of score, but the navigate function cannot pass on the value, it simply shows null on the other end. I would like to ask why is this the case?
The following is my code.

```
const ComponentName = () => {
    const [score, setScore] = React.useState(0);

    const handleNavigate = () => {
        console.log(score);
        navigate("/nextPage", {state: score})
        
    }

    return(
    {someCondition
         ? <Button variant="contained"}>A</Button>
         : <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleNavigate}>B</Button>}

    )
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the `navigate` function call. Only thing I see missing is the `useNavigate` hook. How is the receiving component attempting to access the passed route state? Can you edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include any debugging details tried. Share the expected vs actual results are, and what specific values are being sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentelly, the problem is the value 0.

Maybe have a if statement that if 0 return empty state...

A solution is pass the score as object, like:

`navigate('/nextPage', { state: { score } })`