# useNavigate state is null?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Im trying to figure out why is it that when I use `useNavigate` with my first component the `state` appears `null` when I render my second component?

I've checked the answers found here but did not find any luck :[Cannot pass state using useNavigate() in react router dom v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71588182/cannot-pass-state-using-usenavigate-in-react-router-dom-v6)

Here's my code from first component:

```
export default SignInPage(){

const loginEmailRef = useRef('');
const loginPassWordRef = useRef('');
const navigate = useNavigate();

    return(
      <Box className='sign-in-textfield-box' display='flex' flexDirection='column' alignItems='center'>
                <TextField variant='standard' label='email' sx={{ mb: 2, width: '30vw' }} inputRef={loginEmailRef} />
                <TextField variant='standard' label='password' type='password' sx={{ width: '30vw' }} inputRef={loginPassWordRef} />
                <Button
                    sx={{ mt: 5, fontSize: '17px', }}
                    onClick={async (event) => {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        try {
                            const response = await signInUser(loginEmailRef.current.value, loginPassWordRef.current.value);
                            if (response !== 'error') {
                                console.log('response: ', response);

                                ********************************
                                // response does exist as an object with {name: ..., email:... etc}, but when i pass the response with navigate it says null on my other page
                                  navigate('/HomePage', {state: {response}});
                     
                                ********************************
        
                                //   <Link to={'/HomePage'} state={{state: response} }/>
                            } else {
                                alert('Error signing in: ', response);
                            }
                            // history('/HomePage');
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log('error puhsing to page: ', error);
                        }
                    }}>SignIn</Button>
            </Box>
    );
}
```

Here's the code on my other page:

```
export default HomePage(props) {


const {state} = useLocation();

useEffect( ()=> {

    // here consolo.log says state: null
    console.log(    
        'state: ', state
    );
}, [])
    return(
     <Box> Something here </Box>
);
}
```

EDIT:

Response from `response`

```
Object { 
  providerId: "firebase", 
  proactiveRefresh: {…}, 
  reloadUserInfo: {…}, 
  reloadListener: null, 
  uid: "some-user-id-here", 
  auth: {…}, 
  stsTokenManager: {…}, 
  accessToken: 'some-token-here', 
  displayName: null, 
  email: "t3@testingPurpouseMail.com", … 
}
```

​The initial page is `SignInPage()` then once the user successfully signed it he/she will be redirected to `HomePage()`

My App.js:

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './components/Pages/HomePage/HomePage';
import SignInAndUpPage from './components/Pages/SignInAndUp/SignInAndUpPage';

function App() {
   return (
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<SignInAndUpPage />} />
          <Route path='/HomePage' element={<HomePage />} />
        </Routes>
     </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

EDIT # 2: `signInUser` method:

```
export async function signInUser(email, password) {
    try {
       
       const response = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
       console.log('sign in successful. UID: ', response.user.uid);
       const uid = await loadUserData(response.user.uid)
    
       return response.user;
    } catch (error) {
       console.log('error signin use: ', error.message);
       return 'error';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `console.log('response: ', response);`? Where is `SignInPage` component rendered? Where is `HomePage` rendered? Can you share a more [complete and comprehensive code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: And can you provide also how these components are rendered? I.E. all the routing/navigation code?

Comment: @DrewReese edited! let me know if I udnerstood correctly the routing/naavigation code.

Comment: Ok, assuming there's a router component wrapping the `App` and providing a routing context I don't really see any issue with the code you've shared. Would it be possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue for us to inspect and debug live? If so, please mock the `signInUser` call with the example response object.

Comment: @DrewReese So I have one setup and working as intended (the data is passed through as I wanted when the data is local not from API call). So do you think amybe it is from ```navigate()``` running before ```response``` from SignIn ? But console.log() showed the ```response```

Comment: @DrewReese https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-fire-d29ry2?file=/src/SignInPage.jsx

Comment: I doubt it, since there's an `if-statement` check that appears to pass for you and the navigation occurs. I [fixed the mocking of the `signInUser` function](https://codesandbox.io/s/usenavigate-state-is-null-6j0z4t?file=/src/SignInPage.jsx) so your commented code and be used, and the navigation with state works as I'd expect. Perhaps there's an issue with the `signInUser` function. Can you share that code?

Comment: @DrewReese Edited. The ```signInWithEmailAndPassword()``` method is the method given by firebase. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I've refined the sandbox code a bit. It still appears to function as expected. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we could inspect or debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for your offer to help me out with this issue. I've just been toying around with the code and apparently if I do ```response.user.uid``` (and hell even a custom key:value object works fine too) instead of ```response.user``` in my ```signInUser``` method, the code works and the state is what I expected it to be. So the issue Im thinking is that maybe for whatever reason ```useNavigate``` cannot pass an object from firebase? (the ```typeof response.user``` returns ```object``` in ```console.log```)

Comment: Correct. The state that is sent should be serializable. Perhaps one of those `{...}` values contains a non-serializable object, like a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values sent in route state should be serializable. Perhaps one of these `{...}` response object values contains a non-serializable object, like a function.

> Response from response
>
> ```
> Object { 
>   providerId: "firebase", 
>   proactiveRefresh: {…}, // <-- serializable?
>   reloadUserInfo: {…}, // <-- serializable?
>   reloadListener: null, 
>   uid: "some-user-id-here", 
>   auth: {…}, 
>   stsTokenManager: {…},  // <-- serializable?
>   accessToken: 'some-token-here', 
>   displayName: null, 
>   email: "t3@testingPurpouseMail.com",
>   … 
> }
> ```

For example, functions are typically named using a verb, as in, the function is doing *some* action. The `reloadUserInfo` sounds like it invokes an action.

Instead of blindly passing the entire response object in route state, select only the properties necessary for the receiving route.

Example:

```
const response = await signInUser(
  loginEmailRef.current.value,
  loginPassWordRef.current.value
);

if (response !== 'error') {
  console.log({ response });

  // response does exist as an object with {name: ..., email:... etc}
  const { accessToken, email, name, uid } = response;
  const state = { accessToken, email, name, uid };
  navigate('/HomePage', { state });
} ...
```