# How to navigate to another component using onHeaderCell in antd columns?

Tags: reactjs, antd

## Navigate send props onHeaderCell antd

I try use Cokumn prop *onHeaderCell* of antd in react to navigate to another component I have the follow code columns

```
const columns = [
    {
        title: "Trabajador",
        dataIndex: "trabajador",
        key: "Trabajador",
        render: (text, record) => (
            <a
                onClick={() =>
                navigate("/infoEmployee", { state: { employee: record } })}
            >
            <Text strong style={{ color: "#1677ff" }}>
                {text}
            </Text>
            </a>
          ),
    },
    {
      title: "RUT",
      dataIndex: "CI",
      key: "RUT",
    },
    {
      title: "AMSA: Proyecto operación",
      dataIndex: "AMSA Centinela 4540005270",
      key: "AMSA: Proyecto operación",
      onHeaderCell: (col) => ({
        onClick: () => {
          navigate("/profile", { state: { profile: col } }); //ERROR LINE
          console.log(col); //THIS CONSOLE LOG SHOWS FINE THE col DATA

        },
      }),
      render: (text) =>
        text === "OK" ? (
          <Tag color="green">{text}</Tag>
        ) : (
          <Tag color="red">{text}</Tag>
        ),
    }
]
```

and the another component just shows state variable but is null. the code of another component :

```
export function Profiles({ employee }) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const state = location.state;
    console.log("state", state); //THIS SHOWS state null
}
```

The console.log line whitin onHeaderCell function shows:

```
    {
        "title": "AMSA: Proyecto operación",
        "dataIndex": "AMSA Centinela 4540005270",
        "key": "AMSA: Proyecto operación"
    }
```

I want view the object profile equals to console.log line. Apollogies for my English, I hope you can understand me

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71812067/usenavigate-state-is-null